# как разместить java Server(ServerSocket) на tomcat

Tags: java, android, сервер, сокет

Есть сервер на java работающий с ServerSocket, который обрабатывает соединения. В новых отдельных потоках. Есть клиент (Android приложение), которое "стучится" в нужный порт сервера.

Вопрос в том, как разместить сервер на локальном tomcat'e, чтобы протестировать  клиент с использованием реального устройства через usb?

upd:
а если есть комп без сети/вайфай/инет..на нём надо потестить этот серв и клиент с помощью реального андроид устройства, подключённого в режиме отладки через usb..вопрос: а на какой адрес и порт тогда стучаться из клиента??

Comment: Раз сервер уже работающий, то зачем его вообще куда-то перемещать? Протестировать можно через, что угодно. Хоть через самописный клиент, главное использовать правильный алгоритм, чтобы сервер понял клиент и принял пакет.

Comment: сервер запускаю из IDE и всё работает, а как мне сделать его рабочим без IDE?а точнее если я его в IDE запускаю просто как java приложение то всё норм, он слушает порт и т.д., а если через IDE ложу его на локальный томкат, то ничего не работает, только в браузере открывает index.jsp, который у меня пустой..сервер типа http://www.javaportal.ru/java/articles/ClientServer.html

Comment: Для запуска сервера в режиме ожидания, если в windows - сделать *.bat файл и прописать в нем - все необходимые команды и добавить import главного класса сервера. Если в nix*, то какой-нибудь *.sh - аналог bat.

Comment: а если есть комп без сети/вайфай/инет..на нём надо потестить этот серв и клиент с помощью реального андроид устройства, подключённого в режиме отладки через usb..вопрос: а на какой адрес и порт тогда стучаться из клиента??

Comment: Порт - тот, который вы слушаете сокет-сервером. А IP-адрес разве в ipconfig не виден?

Comment: нет..так не работаект..так работает, если есть общий Wi-fi роутер, а без него нет!

Comment: Какая разница, где он стоит. Важно то, как вы настроите.